# КрадУть чи крАдуть?

Tags: вживання-слів, наголос

На сайті https://zbruc.eu/ в статті про галицькі наголоси знайшла:
вкрадУ (вкрАсти, вкраду, вкрАдеш).

Який правильний наголос в слові крадуть?

Comment: Крашче давати прьаму ланку на статтьу.

Comment: Діалект не є "неправильною мовою", тому вживати можна обидва наголоси.

Comment: напишу класичним правописом те, що хотів сказати пан follower: краще давати пряме посилання на статтю.

Answer (score 1):

Заходимо на сайт [Культура мови](http://kultura-movy.wikidot.com/nagolos) і бачимо:

крАсти, крАдеш, крАду (а відповідно і крАдуть).

Те саме знаходемо і в [блозі](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/hagolos) О. Пономарева та [ось тут](http://clubfate.ukrainianforum.net/t130-topic). Отож, робимо висновки, що правильно казати крАдуть

Answer (score 1):

[Український мовно-інформаційний фонд НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), який я вважаю коли не найнадійнішим, то принаймні найофіційнішим джерелом з приводу наголосів, вважає так:

Дієслово **"в_красти"** для першої особи однини у майбутньому часі має паралельний наголос, можна наголошувати його і на перший **(в_кра́ду)**, і на другий **(в_краду́)** склади.

Решта форм, окрім кількох у наказовому способі, наголошуються лише на перший склад. Наказовий спосіб для другої особи однини, першої й другої особи множини має серед інших форми з наголосом на другий і лише другий склад: **в_кради́, в_краді́мо, в_краді́м, в_краді́ть.**

Додатково надаю таблиці з формами і наголосами:

Додаток 1. Таблиця форм і наголосів для слова "вкрасти":
[image: Таблиця форм і наголосів]

Додаток 2. Таблиця форм і наголосів для слова "красти":
[image: Таблиця форм і наголосів]